# About condtional probabilities

Tags: probability

Consider following exercise: *a machine is working without fault for 8 hours with probability P(A)=90% and for 9 hours with probability P(B)=85%. What is the probability of fault in the ninth hour, provided no prior faults?*

This is a classic exercise from probability textbook.

I thought I was clear on the difference between conditional probability $P(\overline{B} \mid A)$ and intersection $P(A \cap \bar{B})$, but in this particular case I have trouble to gain **intuitive understanding**.

The $P(A \cap \bar{B})$ is probability that the machine won't brake in first 8 hours and will brake in first 9 hours, which sounds the same as probability $P(\overline{B} \mid A)$ that gives probability of fault in first nine hours, provided nothing broke in first 8 hours.

Where is the difference then? If we go from definition, then conditional probability P(A|B) is probability of intersection of the two events, normalized into event space limited only to event B. - it doesn't help to clarify the issue.

The solution:

$P(A \cap \bar{B})=0.9-0.85$

$P(\overline{B} \mid A))=\frac{P(A \cap \bar{B})}{P(A)} = 5.88\%$

Comment: I think you may have some of your $A$ and $B$ in some cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional, means you've already gone through the first 8 hours successfully, and you're wondering what the probability of a failure is in the next hour. It's 5%/90%=5.55%.

Intersection is the probability at the zeroth hour, which is 5% (since it could also still fail in the first 8 hours, which isn't an option above).

Answer (score 0):

The solution you give at the end, symbolically, has the right basic idea (except that you seem to have flipped $A$ and $B$ to represent fault, rather than continuing to work).  The difference between joint probability (the intersection) and conditional probability is perhaps hard to see in this example, because the probability of faults is kind of small.

Suppose, instead, that a machine continues to work in the first eight hours with probabaility $P(A) = 1/2$, and it continues to work in the first nine hours with probability $P(B) = 1/3$.  Obviously, $B$ can happen only if $A$ happens first, so $B \subset A$.

Now, the probability that it works throughout the first eight hours, but fails in the ninth hour, is

$$
P(A \cup \overline{B}) = P(A)-P(B) = 1/6
$$

However, the conditional probability that it fails in the ninth hour, *given* that it worked throughout the first eight hours, is

$$
P(\overline{B} \mid A) = \frac{P(A \cup \overline{B})}{P(A)}
                       = \frac{1/6}{1/2} = 1/3
$$

The difference is that the joint probability considers the event in the context of the entire event space, including those situations where the machine breaks* in the first eight hours, whereas the conditional probability considers only the subset of the event space where the machine worked throughout the first eight hours.

Answer (score 0):

I would say

$P(A|B)\cdot P(B) = P(B|A)\cdot P(A)=1\cdot P(A)\Rightarrow P(A|B)=\frac{P(A)}{P(B)}$

$P(\overline{A}|B)=1-\frac{P(A)}{P(B)}$

Answer (score 0):

The intersection of $P(A \cap \bar{B})$ can be thought of as the probability of event $A$ and $B$ which is why many people refer to $P(A \cap \bar{B})$ as $P(A\bar{B})$. So think of $P(A \cap \bar{B})$ as the probability that both event $A$ and $\bar{B}$ must happen.

Conditional probability of $P(\overline{B} \mid A)$ is the probability of event $\bar{B}$ given that the event $A$ has already happened.

This makes sense in this case since the probability of $P(A \cap \bar{B})$ is less likely to happen compared to the probability of $P(\overline{B} \mid A)$. Ask yourself this question. Is it more likely that the machine will work for $8$ hours $and$ then stop working for the $9th$ or is it more likely that the machine will stop working after it had already worked for $8$ hours.